# How can I update the contents of a CALayer while the main thread is blocked?

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer, avcapturesession

An instance of [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) continues to update its contents from the video capture stream even while the main thread is blocked. Is it possible to generally replicate this behaviour with a custom subclass of `CALayer`? In other words, given raw image data, can we update what is displayed on-screen while the main thread is blocked?

Comment: CATiledLayer is design to work in background thread.

Comment: Not exactly. It loads image tiles on a background thread but still draws them on the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update anything in the view when the main thread is blocked. The whole of UIKit is single-threaded and runs on the main event loop. Video capture is a special case because it draws directly to the screen buffer, but you won't be able to replicate it yourself.

Furthermore, if you do a long-running task on the main thread, iOS will assume your app has crashed and kill it after a few seconds anyway.

Why not perform your other task on a background thread instead? That's the standard practice.

Comment: I hate it when it's possible to do something, but Apple deliberately restricts it... Thanks for the answer - all I needed to know.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an example of that - multithreaded UI is hard to do and few OSes have it - but glad the answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to update the UI on non-UI-Thread.
We can excute the code in any thread, and it actually changes the layer's transform even when the main thread is sleeping.

```
self.labelLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 1.2, 1.0);
```

So if anyone can explain this, please feel free to concat me!